How does mind reading with consent restrict its possible uses?
In my universe, new technology allows for a machine to interface with someone's thoughts nonverbally and communicate them to the outside world, but there's a catch: it only works if the person whose mind is being read does not mentally block the machine by being hostile to the idea of having their mind read. It is not capable of reading the minds of those who refuse consent.
Device Details
The device needed to do this is around the size of a kidney dialysis machine and can be wheeled around, and it needs to be plugged into a special interface pad placed on the person's head in order to work.
While it cannot be used on the dead, it can be used on the unconscious provided they would have consented prior to falling unconscious.
When a person's mind is successfully read, their thoughts are converted into text or images, which are displayed on the machine's screen. This info is then usually either written down  by an attendant or exported into a computer for storage before it disappears. The device cannot display any information the person having their mind read knows to be untrue.
Problem
Since in most fiction, mind reading is almost always used to get critical information out of people who would not otherwise cooperate with those doing the mind reading, how much does this restrict this technology's potential uses?
Focus

[?? What kind of information would be tried to extract?]

Question
EDIT Suggestions:

Is it still possible for adversaries to coerce information out of a person although they could just not "consent" to do so?

Put another way: What are current interrogation techniques that are used without mind reading capabilities?

or: How can a person prevent disclosing information [they could just mentally block it, no?]?



Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

It kind of feels like you're approaching this from the wrong end. Technology doesn't magically appear, it's developed to solve problems. You need to figure out what problem you're trying to solve. Having said that:
A primitive form of this technology already exists. And that article gives you your obvious use case:
People who physically can't talk
Initially, people with disabilities (e.g. Stephen Hawking). Once it's reached the stage you describe, it can be used more widely. Picture the scene: a victim/witness of a crime, lying in hospital, seriously injured and too weak to talk to the police, or even in a coma. Wheel in the thought machine and get a full description of events complete with portrait of the criminal.
Translation
I'm kind of skeptical. Based on the description, it could be used, but when would it be practical? You're not going to wheel a machine around with you as a tourist. For a business meeting, sure, you could, but at the level of an international business you're almost certainly still going to pay for a professional human translator. Though, you might plug in a machine for a secondary confirmation.
A better polygraph
Seems self-explanatory. Most of the limitations of the polygraph are removed. You can still refuse to answer, but silence also says something. How well this works depends on how much you want to stick to the rule that you can't show untruth - you can perhaps explain that by arguing that invention and memory are controlled by different parts of the brain (sounds plausible, at least). Personally I think it adds intrigue if the thought reader can be beaten with training and practice (though it's still a lot harder than a polygraph).
A picture is worth a thousand words
Self-explanatory but very much dependent on how good your image-reading technology is on a scale from etch-a-sketch to professional camera.
All of these boil down two main ideas:

To communicate something that can't be communicated in other ways
To confirm that you are communicating truth

Which of those ideas you use and how brings us back to the starting point - what problem are you trying to solve?

The Willingness to Have Your Mind Read is the Test
We all have secrets we keep to ourselves; some are innocent and some not-so-innocent.
Aunt Ethel is ashamed because, in a fit of unusual anger, she once hit her child.  Uncle Fred embezzled petty cash once.  Cousin Lenny killed a guy when he was drunk.  They're all potential witnesses who could clear you from an accusation, and because mind-reading technology is [claimed to be] absolutely, 100% reliable, any of them willing to submit to a scan could clear you - at the risk of revealing things they would rather keep hidden.
When a witness, a politician, a person accused of a crime, could simply appeal to have their mind read, they could settle the question at hand.  If they would only consent.  But at what risk?  (And just what are you hiding, that you need a third-party witness, instead of undergoing a reading yourself?)
Of course, a politician, soldier, etc, may actually be forbidden to consent - because they know things that must not be revealed.  Top secret things.  Or maybe incriminating things that could topple a government...
But only someone with a clear conscience (relative to the degree of what they're ready to prove - Aunt Ethel stepping forward to your rescue)...  Only a sincere and innocent person (or a special kind of sociopath) would consent to throw wide the doors and let their thoughts and memories be freely probed.  And that very willingness would carry profound weight.
Yes, you could know that accused terrorist 7 did not conspire to bomb that skyscraper (but he did participate in human trafficking)...  Now and then, the certainty would count for something.  But far more often, the mere willingness would (mostly) prove, in the court of public opinion, the profound (or relative) probity of the person giving consent.

so it becomes a test of how good you can lie with the truth, finally a legal system built for politicans.

@John On the contrary, I'm assuming once you "give consent," you lose the ability to limit what can be seen.  Yes, if you can give consent but more or less dodge actually being scanned, it can (and will) be gamed.  But in cases where you really go through with it, you don't get to filter and manipulate what is revealed.  (But who controls what is released from the scans...)

If you read how the machine works it is basically impossible for it to get everything, unless a scan takes years.
